# UICollectionView and cell separators? Is this something to be handled by supplementary views? Decoration views? Within the cell itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a little new to `UICollectionView`, and I'm trying to build a vertical list of items with only one column/only one item per row.

Between each `UICollectionViewCell` I want to have a divider line, similar to `UITableView`'s separator. (No I can't use `UITableView` for this purpose due to other reasons.)

How should I be accomplishing this? Simply adding a 1px high `UIView` to each cell? Use a "supplementary view"? Use a "decoration view"? I'm lost and no tutorials seem to indicate what would be best here.

It seems ridiculous to have to reimplement the full `UICollectionViewLayout` to have some lines, but throwing the line in each cell seems sloppy. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with connection flow layout

You can write this code in viewDidLoad

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
//You can provide vertical


[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:0.0f];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:0.0f];
[self.pictureCollectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.pictureCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
[self.pictureCollectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Set this as your flow layout. I once made a slide show with only one row and a column and added this as a flow layout.

Later use UIEdgeInsets or draw a border of collection cell

Answer (score 2):

Apple’s [Collection View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH5-SW12) says (with my emphasis):

> Decoration views are visual adornments that enhance the appearance of your collection view layouts. Unlike cells and supplementary views, decoration views provide visual content only and are thus independent of the data source. You can use them to provide custom backgrounds, **fill in the spaces around cells**, or even obscure cells if you want.

So decoration views should be ideal for separators. Supplementary views are not appropriate because the data source does not need to customise each separator.

That said, if your requirements aren’t too strict then adding separators into the cells might be easier to implement. Do you need to hide the separator before the first or after the last item? If this isn’t important, you can add separators to the cells and be done in a few minutes.

**Update:** I found animating insertions and deletion while using decoration views as separators did not work well, so do not recommend using decoration views if you need animated updates.

Answer (score 0):

Within Apple's [Implementing Modern CollectionViews](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/implementing_modern_collection_views) sample code from WWDC 2020 they do this by adding a separator view to the bottom of the cell and hiding it if it's the last cell within a section.

```
let numberOfItemsInSection = self.currentSnapshot.numberOfItems(inSection: sectionIdentifier)
let isLastCell = indexPath.item + 1 == numberOfItemsInSection
cell.seperatorView.isHidden = isLastCell
```